# Django Import-Export: Exception Value: no such column

Tags: python, django

My models.py

```
class Camco(models.Model):
    Customer_Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Customer_No=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Customer_Name
```

My admin.py

```
    class CamcoResource(resources.ModelResource):
         class Meta:
            model=Camco
            fields = ('id', 'Customer_Name', 'Customer_No',)     
    class CamcoAdmin(ImportMixin,admin.ModelAdmin):
        recource_class = CamcoResource
        pass

    admin.site.register(Camco,CamcoAdmin)
```

Error

```
OperationalError at /admin/camco/camco/
no such column: camco_camco.Customer_No
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:53430/admin/camco/camco/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: camco_camco.Customer_No
Exception Location: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\agriscbeta\agriscbeta\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 318
```

Comment: Did you run the migration?

Comment: Yes, i have but it still error

Comment: Not sure why your column name shows up in camel case. But I see that you are on windows and if I remember correctly, MySQL, and maybe other databases, converts capital letter to lower case. Try adding in `db_column="customer_no"` in your model field, and do the same for the customer name.